# Get matched data by using jQuery from a json array on the same php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am new to jquery. In my current cakephp page url is:

```
http://localhost/ultimate/admin/treatments/add
```

I have a json array: `<?php $json = $this->Js->object($matchs);?>`the content has: `'[{"Type":{"name":"Items 1","price":"15","duration":"10"}},{"Type":{"name":"Items 2","price":"30","duration":"25"}}]'`

Now I have a name: Items 1, how can I get the price from json array by using Jquery and update to one input area.

Something like this, but I have no idea:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#treatment_foo').change(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'add',
            data: 
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
        $('#fee_foo').val($('#treatment_foo').val());
      },

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I am assuming you are returning this array from PHP in response to the AJAX call?

Comment: Yes, I got that array from cakephp and want to use it in ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success: function(result) {
   $('#fee_foo').val( result[0].Type.price );
},
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I match 'item 1' in json?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `getJson` jQuery function.

**Like**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function($)
    {
        $.getJSON(URL,
        {
            params1: "value",
            params2: "value"
        },
        function(result)
        {
            $.each(result.Type, function(i,item)
            {
                console.log(item.name);
                console.log(item.price);
                console.log(item.duration);
                if ( item.name == 'Item 1' ) return;
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

As you can see you can loop through result `json` and display and compare it as you need,
Cheers...
Feel Free To Ask.